# How to dump resultset data into a database table

Tags: java, sql

I am creating a resultset through an SQL query ('SELECT_PROCESS_INITIAL_REQUEST') which basically just grabs everything out of an SQL database table.

```
Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
String sql = SQLDataAdaptor.SELECT_PROCESS_INITIAL_REQUEST;
ResultSet rsRequest = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
```

I then want to dump that data into an identical table to the original but in a different database. How would I do that?

Comment: Use 2 different `Connections`, one pointing to the source database and another pointing to the target database, and use batch insert to handle the work. Anyway, if you can, it will be better using a ETL tool like Pentaho

Comment: You should execute a statement similar to the one given in [this(using MySQL)](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/1487/copy-an-existing-mysql-table-to-a-new-table/). As you are not modifying any data.

Answer (score 0):

Dumping it in another database means that Java will have to handle your resultset. So i'm afraid you have to do this programmatically.

Think of "prepared statements", "add batch method" and don't forget to execute your inserts every n records.

Answer (score 0):

Using the example on Java Tutorial Website-

```
public static void viewTable(Connection con, String dbName)
throws SQLException {

    //Modify this code according to 2nd database vendor and credentials- 
            String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://MYPC\\SQLEXPRESS;databaseName=MYDB;integratedSecurity=true";
            Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
            Connection conn2 = DriverManager.getConnection(url);

    Statement stmt = null;
    Statement insertStmt = null;
    String query = "select COF_NAME, SUP_ID, PRICE, " +
               "SALES, TOTAL " +
               "from " + dbName + ".COFFEES";
    try {
        stmt = con.createStatement();
        insertStmt = conn2.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
        while (rs.next()) {
            String coffeeName = rs.getString("COF_NAME");
            int supplierID = rs.getInt("SUP_ID");
            float price = rs.getFloat("PRICE");
            int sales = rs.getInt("SALES");
            int total = rs.getInt("TOTAL");

            String insertQuery = "INSERT INTO COFFEES (COF_NAME, SUP_ID, PRICE, sales, total) VALUES (coffeeName,supplierID, proce, sales, total);

           try{
               insertStmt.execute(insertQuery);

           }catch(SQLExeption e){
                e.printStackTrace();
           }
         }
    } catch (SQLException e ) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (stmt != null) { stmt.close();}
        if(insertStmt != null) {insertStmt.close();}
    }
}
```

Comment: You should put the code responsible for connection outside the loop, because in your case in every row will make a new connection to the db, that's huge!!